# jq unsensitive case key filter

Tags: json, bash, key, jq, case-insensitive

From this "test.json" file :

```
{
  "key1": "abc",
  "key2": "def",
  "key3": "ghi"
}
```

I can update "key2" value with the following command :

```
jq '.key2="123"' test.json
```

But, is there a way to use the key filter with case unsensitive and make this command works :

```
jq '.KeY2="123"' test.json
```

And also... to do nothing if the key was not found in the JSON file. The default behavior is to append the searched key.

Comment: You can't make `.KeY2="123"` work, but you _can_ write different jq code that uses completely different syntax to do a case-insensitive match. What's the real use case here? This is a place where details matter.

Comment: Append the searched key as-is or in lowercase?

Comment: (I assume that if the file contains `KeY2` and the user provides `key2` you still want to do the update... right?)

Comment: Both of your proposals work @CharlesDuffy and choroba but only for a key at the root level. I update my question.

Comment: @Floyd, the time to change a question's meaning is _before_ it has answers that correctly answer it as initially asked. Usually, the rule is to accept an answer that's correct for the question the way you originally asked it, and ask a new question if you need to update it in a way that invalidates preexisting answers.

Comment: BTW, given the expanded problem spec -- personally, I'd use Python rather than jq for this. It's certainly doable in jq, but I suspect it'd be shorter and easier to follow in Python.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254521 on [meta]. *Any fundamental changes to a question that change it enough to invalidate correct answers are a no-go.* Rolling back the edits, per same.

Comment: By the way -- environment variable names don't need to be all uppercase. For that matter, the POSIX standard specifies that ones defined by applications that aren't POSIX-specified _shouldn't be_; that specification is widely disregarded, but it's a specification nonetheless (for good reasons; it's safe for an application to give its own meaning to `path` but not `PATH`).

Comment: Yes it makes sense, it's well noted both for the Stackoverflow best practices and for the suggestion towards my problematic. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`test(regex; "i")` can be used to perform a case-insensitive regular expression match in jq. Thus:

```
jq --arg key KeY2 --arg newValue 123 '
  [to_entries[] |
   if .key | test($key; "i") then
     .value = $newValue
   else . end
  ] | from_entries' <test.json
```

That said, being as this is a regex match, you might want to think about how your key name behaves as a regex -- anchoring, etc. An alternative is to convert both versions to lowercase for the comparison only:

```
jq --arg key KeY2 --arg newValue 123 '
  ($key | ascii_downcase) as $lower_key |
  [to_entries[] |
   if (.key | ascii_downcase) == $lower_key then
     .value = $newValue
   else . end
  ] | from_entries' <test.json
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ascii_downcase` to get the lowercase version of the key:

```
jq --arg k Key1 '(.[$k | ascii_downcase] // empty) = "123"'
```

The `// empty` part prevents the creation of the key.

Comment: Are you sure this is what the OP is asking for? This looks like another case-sensitive match, just with an all-lowercase version.

Comment: I'm not sure but that's what I understood. The OP has the key name specified in mixed case in the `jq` expression, not in the input JSON file.

Comment: ...whereas a true case-insensitive match would work if _either_ side has the wrong case. It's the OP who can say for sure, but to me this reads like overfitting to the sample data at the expense of compliance with the prose description (though it could as well be a question asked with imprecise prose).

Comment: See the OP's edit to the question. "If my environment variables are uppercase, I don't know which case have the keys in the target JSON files (this script will be used in different application containers)" -- so they don't know that lowercase is correct.

Comment: (that's from a now-rolled-back revision; see https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/67725386/4)